# MySQL query running a long time converting datetime to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query fairly optimized. However, when I add this join it increases the query by 70 seconds. The biggest problem I can see is that I have to compare two datetimes to each other based on the same date. In other words 2013-01-01 8:37am must join to 2013-01-01 9:01am. So, I first convert both to dates, then I compare them.

Is there a faster way to do this without modifying the tables? I've added indexes to all the fields in the join below.

```
LEFT JOIN ins ON 
DATE(ins.ins_date) = DATE(r.date)
```

**UPDATE: Ended up trying a few different tricks, such as subtracting a few hours from the date and comparing the dates directly will leverage at least one index, and adding more criteria to the join helps reduce the records it attempts to perform the DATE() operation on. I believe the poster below also had a valid suggestion of creating a separate field for the date but I can't modify the table for this case, but I may try this in the future.**

Comment: Your index probably isn't helping because the values indexed are `ins.ins_date` and `r.date`, not `DATE(ins.ins_date)` and `DATE(r.date)`. Try running `DESCRIBE <query>` to see if the indexes are being used.

Comment: Best way is to alter table and maintain one more column for only date.

Answer (score 1):

In the join statement you showed us, you are transforming the datetime (into a plain date) in order to compare it.  That means that the database engine will have to examine *every* *single* *record* in the table to see if they meet the criteria you're after.   Even if you have an index on `ins_date`, the engine will not be able to use it to find the records you're after.

See if you can re-craft the query to use the columns in their `native` form (i.e. without any transformation applied to them).   If you have to apply some kind of transformation to a column in order to do a join or filter, try to do it only to the tiniest table in that join, to reduce the number of records that have to be retrieved and transformed.

If you can, and this is a query that runs more than only occasionally, see if you can redefine the columns you are using to DATE rather than DATETIME types.  If you need the time portion of the DATETIME value in your application(s), then see if you can maintain a ghost DATE column with only the DATE portion of that DateTime value (this can be maintained by the insert queries, or by a trigger).